# Neo4j : updating relationship is taking too long, 20s

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How come such a query can take 20 seconds ?

> MATCH (node)-[n]-() WHERE ID(n) = 5022545 SET n.`updated_at`= 1463694178 ,n.`count`= 3

while

> MATCH (node)-[n]-() WHERE ID(n) = 5022545 RETURN n

is immediate...
is there a way to find out what takes time ?

thanks

Comment: Use Neo4j 3.x then the COST planner will be used for both of your queries.

Comment: in 2.x use: cypher planner=rule explain start n=rel(5022545) SET n.updated_at= 1463694178 ,n.count= 3

Comment: Michael, that works like a charm, thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4j provides two helpers for you: `EXPLAIN` AND `PROFILE`. EXPLAIN will show you the general query plan, while `PROFILE` will give you a better idea of what resources are being consumed (basically, where all the work is happening).

So... run something like:

```
PROFILE MATCH (node)-[n]-()
WHERE ID(n) = 5022545
SET n.updated_at= 1463694178 ,n.count= 3
```

Comment: thanks. sounds bad, Traversal Matcher indicates 21,558,384 
db hits with PROFILE. How come it needs to do so to update a property on a relationship ?

Comment: That sounds like a different question. :)